# How to set the current axes to a dataframe in Matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have code that reads a csv file and then uses a scatterplot to map the 3 columns to a plot.  Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pylot as plt
import pandas as pd

x = []
y = []
df = pd.read_csv("csvFile.csv")
print(df) # Sanity check.  Shows x, y, and lbl column data.
ax = plt.gca() # Get the current instance
ax = df.plot('x', 'y', kind='scatter')
numberOfFigures = plt.getfignums()
print(numberOfFigures) # Here I get two figures because I think ax isn't the # current instance?
# Print returns [1,2]

... other code that does a fill, legend, etc. that I believe is immaterial to the question.
plt.show()
```

So my question is how do I get the dataframe to load the x,y datapoints and the labels into the current figure instead of two figures and splitting things up?  It's creating a blank figure and the data in another figure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a simpler way to plot a scatter plot from a DataFrame would be something like this using the iris dataset as an example:

```
 for species, color in colors.items():
 plt.scatter(df[df['species'] == species]['petal_length'],
                df[df['species'] == species]['sepal_length'],
                c=color,
                alpha=0.8,
                label=species)

plt.legend(loc="lower right")

plt.title("Iris Petal Length Vs Sepal Length")

plt.xlabel("Petal Length")

plt.ylabel("Sepal Length")

plt.show()
```

[image]

I hope it helps!